# How to call a success function with a variable in $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

In Javascript how would I make something like this work:

```js
function callAjax (url, successCallback, errorCallback)
{
  var ajaxProps = {
    url: url,
    success: successCallback,
    error: errorCallback
  }
  return $.ajax(ajaxProps);
}
```

I keep getting errors or they are undefined no matter how I try to do it.  I'm trying to slowly break things out from a god object.  So normally the ajax call would be to parent.specificSuccess since it's from within that object.  I've also tried using godObject[successCallback] and global[namespace].godObject[successCallback].  I've also tried all three of those variations with:

```js
function callAjax (url, successCallback, errorCallback)
{
  var ajaxProps = {
    url: url,
    success: function (response) {
      successCallback(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
      errorCallback(response);
    }
  }
  return $.ajax(ajaxProps);
}
```

It's being called from within the god object with:

```js
callAjax('https://url.com', specificSuccess, specificError);
```

I've tried all three options listed above and using "parent" in front of it as well.

I know I must be missing something, I've never run into an instance of being asked to do something like this before.  It seems like I should be able to call a method in a callback using a variable with the method's name...but Google has failed me on this.

Comment: unsure why they would not work....

Answer (score 0):

I have an example. It works perfectly for me. You can save this code as .js file and refer in your web page. you call the ajax method like this: backend.ajax.AjaxPOST() passing the parameters. Optionaly you can have a Loading.

```
backend.ajax = {

AjaxPOST: function (url, data, dataType, callBackSucess, callBackError, loadig) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: dataType,
        success: function (e) {
            if (callBackSucess != null)
                callBackSucess(e);
        },
        beforeSend: function (e) {
            if (loadig == true)
                startLoadingAjax();
        },
        complete: function (e) {
            if (loadig == true)
                endLoadingAjax();
        }
    });
},

AjaxGET: function (url, dataType, callBackSucess, callBackError, loadig) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: dataType,
        success: function (e) {
            if (callBackSucess != null)
                callBackSucess(e);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            if (callBackError != null)
                callBackError(e);
        },
        beforeSend: function (e) {
            if (loadig == true)
                startLoadingAjax();
        },
        complete: function (e) {
            if (loadig == true)
                endLoadingAjax();
        }
    });
}};


var divLoading = "<div id=\"Loading\" style=\"display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 1000; top: 0;left: 0; height: 100%;width: 100%;background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;display:block;\"></div>";

function startLoadingAjax() {
$("body").append(divLoading);}

function endLoadingAjax() {
$("#Loading").remove();}
```